# Solving single term recurrence relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

$a_n = -3a_{n-1}\\
a_0 = 2$

Therefore

$a_1 = -3(2) = -6\\
a_2 = -3(-6) = 18\\
a_3 = -3(18) = 54$

So... $x^n = -3^{n-1}$? If so $x^2 = -3^1$, so $x^2 + 3 = 0$, then $x = \pm (i\sqrt3)$. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: I think you want to replace $a_n$ by $x^n$ and $a_{n-1}$ by $x^{n-1}$. Then you will solve for $x$, and use the initial conditions to find the constant.

Comment: So $x^n = -x^{n-1}$ instead of what I wrote?

Comment: $a_n = -3a_{n-1}$ becomes $x^n = -3x^{n-1}$.

Comment: Thanks I got it. So $x^n = -3^n * 2$

Comment: Just need to be careful, it is $a_n = (-3)^n \cdot 2$.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to see that $a_n = 2 \cdot (-3)^n$. You can prove this by induction.